# Failed to export application when using Proguard

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, proguard

I'm using **ADT 23.0.1.1256982** (*win7-32bit, eclipse, API 20 with google play services librar(ies)*)  and so the `proguard-android.txt` file is missing per default.

Therefore I created it manually and copied the content from here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/android-4.1.2_r2/files/proguard-android.txt

But when I try to export the signed application the **Export Wizards** fails with error message:

```
"failed to export application"
```

This does not happen when I don't use **Proguard**.

I've absolutely no idea how to solve this problem. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android Studio or Eclipse?
If Android Studio, make sure it's on app source folder, besides the folders build and src, and check if it's declared like this on you build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        zipAlign true
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

Additionally, just for knowledge, in API 20+ Google has changed the name from 'proguard-rules.txt' to 'proguard-rules.pro'

If the problem still persists, try using comand line instead the wizard.

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

When it's completed, the apk will be on your project folder. Just look up for *.apk and you'll see it there.

Comment: Unfortunetely I'm using eclipse

Comment: Is it possible to get more informations about the error occured?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know about it on Eclipse.